# memory errors while reading a large file in C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I am very novice in working with malloc/realloc in C and so need some help. The following is short snippet of a big program where I intend to read a big (fasta) file almost 80000 line numbers and store the first line marked with > (name) and following line (sequence) in two separate arrays- fasta_name and fasta_seq. I have used a standard library which gives the output as a structure but I need to change it into arrays since later on the program I need to check input provided by the user with each of the fasta entries in the file..

The inputfile format is:

> P21306\n
>   MSAWRKAGISYAAYLNVAAQAIRSSLKTELQTASVLNRSQTDAFYTQYKNGTAASEPTPITK\n
>   P38077\n
>   MLSRIVSNNATRSVMCHQAQVGILYKTNPVRTYATLKEVEMRLKSIKNIEKITKTMKIVASTRLSKAEKA\n

=======================

The code is:

KSEQ_INIT(gzFile, gzread) ///EXTERNAL LIBRARY FOR BIOLOGISTS READING FASTA FORMAT FILE///

```
  int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {

char **fasta_name=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*80000);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    fasta_name[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
}
char **fasta_seq=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char *)*80000);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    fasta_seq[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5000);
}

fpf = gzopen("fasta_seq_nr_uniprot.txt", "r"); 
seq = kseq_init(fpf); 

while((l = kseq_read(seq)) >= 0) 
{ 
    strcpy(fasta_name[index1],seq->name.s);
    strcpy(fasta_seq[index1],seq->seq.s);
    index1++;
}

kseq_destroy(seq); 
    gzclose(fpf); 

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    free(fasta_name[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    free(fasta_seq[i]);
}

free(fasta_name);
free(fasta_seq);
```

The program shows no compilation errors but the following memory errors and segmentation fault using Valgrind.

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./Gwidd_uniprot_map2 xaa==3511== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3511== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3511== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3511== Command: ./map2 xaa
==3511== 
--3511-- ./map2:
--3511-- dSYM directory has wrong UUID; consider using --dsymutil=yes
Opening file xaa
==3511== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3511==    at 0x100012C43: __strcpy_chk (mc_replace_strmem.c:893)
==3511==    by 0x100001A78: __inline_strcpy_chk (in ./map2)
==3511==    by 0x10000183E: main (in ./map2)
==3511==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3511==    at 0x100011345: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3511==    by 0x10000170C: main (in ./map2)
==3511== 
==3511== Invalid write of size 1
==3511==    at 0x100012C43: __strcpy_chk (mc_replace_strmem.c:893)
==3511==    by 0x100001A78: __inline_strcpy_chk (in ./map2)
==3511==    by 0x10000183E: main (in ./map2)
==3511==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3511== 
==3511== 
==3511== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3511==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3511==    at 0x100012C43: __strcpy_chk (mc_replace_strmem.c:893)
==3511==    by 0x100001A78: __inline_strcpy_chk (in ./map2)
==3511==    by 0x10000183E: main (in ./map2)
==3511==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3511==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3511==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3511==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3511==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3511== 
==3511== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3511==     in use at exit: 6,674,813 bytes in 3,664 blocks
==3511==   total heap usage: 3,807 allocs, 143 frees, 6,698,108 bytes allocated
==3511== 
==3511== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3511==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3511==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3511==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3511==    still reachable: 6,674,813 bytes in 3,664 blocks
==3511==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3511== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3511== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3511== 
==3511== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3511== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

CODE EDITED AS:

```
char **fasta_name=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*80000);
if(fasta_name == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    fasta_name[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    if(fasta_name[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
char **fasta_seq=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char *)*80000);
if(fasta_seq == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    fasta_seq[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5000);
    if(fasta_seq[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

fpf = gzopen("fasta_seq_nr_uniprot.txt", "r"); 
seq = kseq_init(fpf); 
while((l = kseq_read(seq)) >= 0) 
{ 
    strcpy(fasta_name[index1],seq->name.s);
    strcpy(fasta_seq[index1],seq->seq.s);
    index1++;
}
kseq_destroy(seq); 
gzclose(fpf);
```

Comment: `malloc` can return `NULL`, you should check for that.

Comment: code modified without any change in error output..

Comment: In C don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: I'd run it in the debugger so you can see what exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: I will try to run it in the debugger but prior to that can anyone suggest if this copying of structure member into array as in the line: strcpy(fasta_name[index1],seq->name.s) is fine or not??

Comment: It's fine if the destination pointer points to a valid chunk of allocated memory large enough to handle all of the characters copied from the source + 1 for the NULL at the end, and the source pointer points to a valid location.  The debugger will help you figure out which of those is not true.

Comment: there are two problems with the code, that are immediately obvious.  1) the variable 'size' is used in two places, but is never initialized to any value.  2) the variable 'index1' is never initialized to the initial value of 0.  I also do not see where those two variables are even declared.  It would be wise to include the definition of the 'seq' and I wonder, as does the OP, about the two strcpy function calls, as I see no null terminated strings being defined to be copied

Comment: your code needs to check the 'fpf' returned from gzopen to assure it is not null.

Comment: I had mentioned in the first that this is only a small chunk of a big program which is creating memory problems and had indicated the incomplete portions by ====== But somebody had removed those dashed signs and edited my code. Anyways, the program indeed have int size=80000, l=0, index1=0 etc etc and shouldn't be a cause of worry..

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error `Access not within mapped region at address`, I would say that you are accessing memory that's out of bounds, causing your segmentation fault. Check that `malloc()` doesn't return NULL to you after calling it, otherwise you risk accessing memory you don't actually own.

Do this after every single `malloc()` call. For example:

```
int *i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
if(!i){
   fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong with malloc(), exiting...\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Another thing to check is to see if index1 is out of bounds of your allocations. I don't see where it's declared or initialized. Is it possible that your allocation for fasta_name and others is too small, given that you read information using a while loop that keeps incrementing the index?

Comment: Unless this is a C++ program, there's no need to cast the result of `malloc`. And, in fact, you don't want to cast the result in C, because doing so can hide bugs.